# UNIX SVR4.2 > How do I find the IP address on a Virtualbox system?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, historical-unix

I have installed a VirtualBox VM of UNIX System V Release 4.2 and have discovered just how barren the internet is on documentation of it. Only a few modern commands exist, although obviously because the shell is just sh, not bash, which I'm more used to. I can't get syntax help without `man` and there doesn't seem to be any `help` or `--help`. And I have to use "-linux" (subtract results with term 'linux') in all Google searches to get any semi-useful results.

Try as I might, I cannot find anything that has the old commands listed for finding the system's IP address, and nothing useful shows up for finding it directly in VirtualBox's settings.

I have the network setup packages which came with the old system so I want to see if it can at least try to see the network, but in order to install them I need the IP.

Please help if you have any experience at all.

Comment: You've tried `/sbin/ifconfig`?

Comment: Which manufacturer's flavour of SVR4.2 have you got? I've a niggle that the networking tools weren't standardised back then

Comment: You might get some help over in [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) - but I haven't recently checked their "What can I ask about here?"

Comment: Ensure that `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and, if they exist, `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/bin` are in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @waltinator [sbin path and no ifconfig](https://i.imgur.com/OAGr20P.png)

Comment: @roaima [don't know about flavor but this is the full version info I know of](https://i.imgur.com/cOmoYfN.png)

Comment: @Asteroid pictures of cats don't help, I'm afraid. Which manufacturer's version of SVR4.2 did you download?

Comment: @roaima Well this is where I got it: https://archive.org/details/UNIXSystemVRelease4.21.0/20181202_133534.png

Comment: Those pictures... can you [please put the _text_ into your question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: The commands aren't missing because you're not using bash. `--help` doesn't exist because you're not using GNU. Many tools may use `-h` instead, but the man page was (and still is) the primary place you're supposed to look.

Comment: If you're asking what the OS is configured to use, isn't it whatever you typed in?
If you're asking what you need to put to make networking work, what is your network configuration in the VM settings in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

A full distribution of UNIX SVR4.2 should have `ifconfig` somewhere. If it is not in your `PATH`, you may have to search it with `find`.

You may also look if the IP address is present in `/etc/hosts`; normally it has a line there with the hostname.

I think `hostname` was also present; it should be `hostname -i` to get the IP address.

If everything else fails, you could `grep 192.168 /etc/* /etc/*/*` or something like that. Assuming that you know at least part of the IP address.

Comment: You probably want `hostname -I` for all addresses.

Comment: Not sure that Sys V supported `-I`; I thought it was a GNU extension.

Comment: Ah, quite possibly